# Positioning an administrator-defined content part

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

How should I go about controling the position of a content part I've created using the administration interface (Content Definition -> Content Parts)? To be precise, I want to hide it from the summary view and show it just in details. I created the part to try to simplify positioning of its fields - show/hide them all at once so that fields can be easily administered as necessary without having to change anything else.

I tried using placement.info to position the part, even tried adding a template to no avail... I might have missed the part shape's name. Looking at shape trace for the page, the part is nowhere to be seen in the model - instead, its fields seem to be added directly to content. (Correction: it's there in the model, but not in the display treeview on the left).

Is there a way to do this in Orchard? I'm using the newest one - 1.9.1.

EDIT:

Here's the placement.info that I tried. The content part in question is called FilmData, and I've noticed in the debugger that it does appear in the Parts collection as an instance of ContentPart, but it doesn't seem to get through to the shape trace as a whole.

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_FilmData="-"/>
    <Place Parts_FilmData_Summary="-"/>
    <Place Parts_FilmDataPart="-"/>
    <Place Parts_FilmDataPart_Summary="-"/>
    <Place Parts_ContentPart="-"/>
    <Place Parts_ContentPart_Summary="-"/>
...
```

This has no effect, neither in the summary nor in the detail view.

I also tried adding a CSHTML template and calling it -

```
Views\Content-FilmData.cshtml
Views\Content-FilmData.Summary.cshtml
Views\FilmData.cshtml
Views\Parts.FilmData.cshtml
Views\Parts.FilmData.Summary.cshtml
Views\DisplayTemplates\Parts\FilmData.cshtml
```

... but none of these seem to get used.

This is what I get in the left frame of shape trace... Note that Parts_Film is a different part, it was created programmatically. The fields that can be seen here are the ones from the FilmData part.

```
Content
    Parts_Title
[+] Fields_MediaLibraryPicker
    Parts_Film
    Fields_Input
    Fields_Input
    Fields_Input
    Fields_Input
    Fields_Input [empty]
[+] Fields_DateTime
    Fields_TaxonomyField
    Parts_Common_Body
    Parts_Contents_Publish [empty]
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried in the placement.info? I'm not aware of any way to do this directly through the UI.

Comment: I added more details to the question. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: To make sure I understand, is your part currently displaying at all?

Comment: Well, the answer is mostly yes - and I understand why you ask. The contents of the part's fields do show up on the page, but I cannot find the part itself with the shape trace. In the shape trace window, the part is not present in the (shapes?) treeview at left although it's there in the model tab - it's a child of the content item. The result seems to be the same as if I'd added the fields directly to the content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer here is that what you are trying to do will not work because fields, even though they are attached to particular part, are not displayed through that part hence would not respect whether or not the part is displayed or not.

This is a little more detail if you want it... Although a part in Orchard can exist outside of code, how it works (what it displays, what data it stores etc.) is all defined within code. One thing you need is a driver with a display method that will register a content shape.

```
protected override DriverResult Display(MyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    return ContentShape("Parts_MyPart",
        () => { return shapeHelper.Parts_MyPartView(Model: part); });
}
```

So the "Parts_MyPart" bit is what is matched by placement to decide if and where to display your view, which is the Parts_MyPartView shape. This is important to note because as you discovered trying various placement statements, you can actually have anything there (most people follow Orchard's conventions which are used by all the core parts). As for views, creating a part from the UI will not actually display anything. The first two templates you tried (using the Content- prefix) are used to override the main content template, so you would use your content type name there, not a part name (shameless plug: you can read a little more about those in one of my badly written blog posts, http://arkleseizure.net/what-the-hell-is-an-item-template).

Hope that helped clear things up a little.